# Find Roman numerals up to 100 that do not contain “I"

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, filtering

The question is from Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language, section 28 Tests and Conditionals: Find Roman numerals up to 100 that do not contain “I”.

What am I doing wrong that the following code is not returning the desired output?

```
Select[RomanNumeral[Range[100]], MemberQ[#, "I"]&]
```

I can't quite figure out where I am going wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: MemberQ is for lists. So, you could split the string into characters first (and use Not). Or you could just use StringFreeQ on the roman numeral strings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Roman numerals are strings, not lists (or another expression).  So `MemberQ` will return `False`.

```
Select[RomanNumeral[Range[100]],
 ! MemberQ[Characters@#, "I"] &]
```

Or:

```
Select[RomanNumeral[Range[100]], StringFreeQ["I"]]
```

Also:

```
RomanNumeral[Range[5, 100, 5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: [Roman zero N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Zero) gets no respect.  

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Mma respects it: `RomanNumeral[Range[0, 100, 5]]`. It's unclear whether *nulla* was considered a number, or even whether N was used by the Romans since, according to the Wiki article, "the earliest attested instances are medieval."

Comment: Much of the rules about Roman numbers achieved their greater uniformity (as in this good answer) long after Roman times.  Else `XXXX,` (and the like) should be on the list too.

Answer (score 10):

I include some variations.

```
rn100 = RomanNumeral@Range@100;


Cases[rn100, _?(StringFreeQ["I"])]

DeleteCases[rn100, _?(StringContainsQ["I"])]

DeleteCases[rn100, _?(StringMatchQ[___ ~~ "I" ~~ ___])]

Complement[rn100, Cases[rn100, _?(StringMatchQ[___ ~~ "I" ~~ ___])]] //
  SortBy[#, FromRomanNumeral] &

Pick[rn100, StringMatchQ["*I*"] /@ rn100, False]

Pick[rn100, StringMatchQ[Except["I"] ..]@rn100]

Select[rn100, # == StringDelete[#, "I"] &]

Select[rn100, StringPosition[#, "I"] == {} &]
```

---

Result:

{"V", "X", "XV", "XX", "XXV", "XXX", "XXXV", "XL", "XLV", "L", "LV", 
"LX", "LXV", "LXX", "LXXV", "LXXX", "LXXXV", "XC", "XCV", "C"}

Comment: Now that's just flexing.

Answer (score 5):

Another way using `GroupBy` and `Extract`:

```
rn100 = RomanNumeral@Range@100;

Extract[GroupBy[rn100, FreeQ[Characters[#], "I"] &], Key[True]]
```

Or using `GroupBy` and `Lookup`:

```
Lookup[GroupBy[rn100, FreeQ[Characters[#], "I"] &], True]
```

Or using `ReplaceAll`:

```
rn100 /. x_?StringQ /; ! StringFreeQ[x, "I"] :> Nothing
```

**Edit** Thanks to the comment by @eldo, there's a shorter version using `GroupBy:

```
GroupBy[rn100, FreeQ[Characters[#], "I"] &][True]
```

Answer (score 3):

Or use regex.

> "Now you have two problems"

```
Range[100] // RomanNumeral // Select[StringMatchQ[RegularExpression["[^I]*"]]]
```

https://xkcd.com/1171/ Perl Problems